Folder on NAS not accessible by Windows, network credentials give access denied
I have a home NAS setup (running openmediavault 5.5.6-1, outdated I know, but it does the job) where I recently backed up my files to. Lucky that I did, because two weeks ago my SSD got damaged/corrupted and I had to do a clean Windows install on another SSD. Now I am trying to retrieve the backup from the NAS, but I am getting an error when trying to access the main backup folder. I can however access the other folders on the NAS, such as my Pictures and Movies folders. I checked in the OMV control panel and the access settings appear to be the same for all folders there. Also, I was (of course) able to access this folder from the Windows distribution on my old SSD.
When trying to log in, I am met with an "Access is denied". This happens for both the OMV credentials (admin and root) and for the credentials of my Microsoft account. I have come across various similar situations online but could not find my fix between them. I have tried:

Removing/re-adding Windows credentials in the Credentials Manager. I did both with my OMV credentials and my Microsoft credentials, to no avail.

Changing the advanced network sharing settings. My current settings are:


Private
Turn on network discovery with turn on automatic setup of network connected devices
File and printer sharing turned on
Guest or public
Turn on network discovery
Turn on fie and printer sharing
All Networks
Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the Public folders
Use 128-bit encryption
Turn off password protected sharing

Running the secpol.msc command, navigating to Local Policies -> Security Options and disabling Accounts: limit local use of blank passwords to console logon only

None of these solve my issue, I am at my wits' end. Could anyone please help me?
Screenshot of the error
